# How to make a powering up shield sound

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I could use help going in the right direction for designing a shield being powered up sound.Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome! Before we can help you out, help us by answerring some questions:
1. What have you already tried?
2. Why didn't that work?
3. What is the context of the sound?